# Get Account Details Data Missing

Tags: accounts, ios-sdk

I am getting the following error when calling getAccountDetails using the iOS SDK:

```
parsingResponseFailed(message: "The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.")
```

Here is my code. This should use testnet:

```
let accountId = "GD7RK5UAKK3U2F5ZM7JSELONZ6MYONDDJWV3DGKENJVUQB52DR3FYVK3"
StellarSDK().accounts.getAccountDetails(accountId: accountId) { (response) -> (Void) in
            print(response)
        }
```

The StellarSDK class is initialized using the testnet url:

```
public class StellarSDK: NSObject {

    public var horizonURL: String
    ...

    public override init() {
        horizonURL = "https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org"
        ...
```

And the account is visible on the testnet when called through the Stellar lab:

https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GD7RK5UAKK3U2F5ZM7JSELONZ6MYONDDJWV3DGKENJVUQB52DR3FYVK3

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Comment: It's possible that it's happening because there are some breaking changes in Horizon 0.18.0 rc1: https://github.com/Soneso/stellar-ios-mac-sdk/issues/66

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's because of the missing paging token. A new release ([1.6.6](https://github.com/Soneso/stellar-ios-mac-sdk/releases/tag/1.6.6)) is now available that fixes that issue.